# How to open a popup on click of button placed in menu page in master detail page in xamarin forms?

Tags: popup, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms. I am using Master detail page. In menupage of MasterDetailPage I have some menu items that are listed. At the bottom of the Menu list I placed a button on menu page. Now I need to open a popup on click of that button. I am trying with PopupLayout but not able to get any success.

Please tell me how I can open a custom popup box at the click of the button that is placed in menu page?

Regards,
Anand Dubey

Comment: How it should looks?  Maybe `Acr.UserDialogs` will be acceptable?

Comment: No, I need to open my own layout in the popup. So I can'not open Acr.UserDialogs. I am trying to use PopupLayout to open my content layout. But not getting any success. Do you know how I can open my own layout as a popup?

Comment: You will need to be **way** more specific than "not getting any success". Are you talking about the XLabs PopupLayout? Did you see their documentation, samples? Have you searched for similar issues others might have had?

Comment: Yes, I am already using PopupLayout. And yes it is XLabs popuplayout. It is working fine if it is placed at xaml page. But I need to use it through menu list from Master detail page. In that case its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into separate, native projects for all platforms you are targeting (such as Android, iOS, UWP...), you cannot pop out custom UI content over existing pages in Xamarin.Forms out of the box. You would need to bring in additional references or get creative with the AbsoluteLayout control.
Here are a few options you have:

### Simple popup with message and or option selection

If all you need is a simple popup message or a list of buttons, you should look into the native DisplayAlert and DisplayActionSheet methods. They are built into Xamarin.Forms and work really well for these simple cases.

### More complex popup dialogs

For anything more complex than that, there is the excellent UserDialogs project: [ACR UserDialogs github page](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)
It will give you support for various loading dialogs, date, time pickers, action sheet, success/info/error toasts and more.

### Fully custom UI markup with AbsoluteLayout

There is a technique where by you prepare the underlying page with a root absoltue layout, which enables you to dynamically add new UI on top of all other controls on your page. This is fiddly and can ruin your performance if you are not careful. This is also the approach that the PopupLayout control that you mentioned uses. If done properly, this can be a good solution, but I don't recommend it as it involves additional complexity on each page that hosts the popup content.

### Fully custom UI popup on native projects

Your most flexible option, as always, is to fall back to the native projects. This would involve coding up the popup logic on each separate platform that you are targeting, then using DependencyService (or one of the other techniques) to call into it from the shared project. For this you should look at samples and tutorials for popups on separate native platforms as it gets pretty broad and goes way outside the topic of this question.